# Trying to pass List<T> in post method using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Trying to pass List in post method using Spring boot MVC, I am trying to pass a json array to a rest api which take a List but It says the Request body is not in proper Format.

This is the JSON Format I am passing

```
[{"quotation":100001,"customer":"ZOMRAN KHALED MEDICAL UNIT",
  "currency":"Algerian dinar (DZD)","country":"Algeria","language":"English",
  "product":"9100C","modality":"LCS","subModality":"ARC","services":"PM,CM",
  "serviceType":"SWIFT","price":"1500","responseTime":"24H","createdTime":"24/04/2018"},

  {"quotation":100002,"customer":"ZOMRAN KHALED MEDICAL UNIT",
  "currency":"Algerian dinar (DZD)","country":"Algeria","language":"English",
  "product":"9100C","modality":"LCS","subModality":"ARC","services":"PM,CM",
  "serviceType":"SWIFT","price":"1500","responseTime":"24H","createdTime":"24/04/2018"}
  ]
```

This is my Java controller where I am catching the array.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/carePlanQuotationHistory", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody Response CarePlanQuotationHistory1(@RequestBody List<CarePlanHistoryRequest> carePlanQuotationHistory1) throws Exception {
    int a;
    try {
        a = productService.CarePlanQuotationHistory1(carePlanQuotationHistory1);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return new Response("400", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return new Response("200", a);
}
```

This is my pojo

```
package com.careplan.springbootstarter.request;

public class CarePlanHistoryRequest {



    private String quotation; 
    private String customer;
    private String currency;
    private String country;
    private String language;
    private String product;
    private String modality;
    private String subModality;
    private String services;
    private String serviceType;
    private String price;
    private String responseTime;
    private String createdTime;
    public CarePlanHistoryRequest() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public CarePlanHistoryRequest(String quotation, String customer, String currency, String country, String language,
            String product, String modality, String subModality, String services, String serviceType, String price,
            String responseTime, String createdTime) {
        super();
        this.quotation = quotation;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.country = country;
        this.language = language;
        this.product = product;
        this.modality = modality;
        this.subModality = subModality;
        this.services = services;
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
        this.price = price;
        this.responseTime = responseTime;
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }
    public String getQuotation() {
        return quotation;
    }
    public void setQuotation(String quotation) {
        this.quotation = quotation;
    }
    public String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    public void setCustomer(String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
    public String getModality() {
        return modality;
    }
    public void setModality(String modality) {
        this.modality = modality;
    }
    public String getSubModality() {
        return subModality;
    }
    public void setSubModality(String subModality) {
        this.subModality = subModality;
    }
    public String getServices() {
        return services;
    }
    public void setServices(String services) {
        this.services = services;
    }
    public String getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
    }
    public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getResponseTime() {
        return responseTime;
    }
    public void setResponseTime(String responseTime) {
        this.responseTime = responseTime;
    }
    public String getCreatedTime() {
        return createdTime;
    }
    public void setCreatedTime(String createdTime) {
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }


}
```

**This is the Error we are getting**

```
{
    "timestamp": 1526647767010,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.careplan.springbootstarter.entity.Customer] from String value ('ZOMRAN KHALED MEDICAL UNIT'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@46f9d4f8; line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.careplan.springbootstarter.entity.CarePlanQuotationHistory[\"customer\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.careplan.springbootstarter.entity.Customer] from String value ('ZOMRAN KHALED MEDICAL UNIT'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@46f9d4f8; line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.careplan.springbootstarter.entity.CarePlanQuotationHistory[\"customer\"])",
    "path": "/api/product/carePlanQuotationHistory"
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Entransys</groupId>
  <artifactId>CarePlanConfig</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CarePlanConfig Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.12</version>
</dependency>

            <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
        </plugin>

<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
      <execution>
          <id>copy-resources</id>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
          <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static/</outputDirectory >
              <resources>
                  <resource>
                      <directory>${basedir}/../care-plan-client/dist</directory >
                  </resource>
              </resources>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>



    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Post your pom.xml as well

Comment: Error speaks about a `Customer` class, could you show it ?

Comment: at first glance, it seems like `quotation` should be a number not a String. So either you add quotes to the value `"quotation": "100001"` or change the type to int or another number type.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Your exception talks about `com.careplan.springbootstarter.entity.Customer` But I can't find that class in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the JSON you are passing in is formatted incorrectly. You have defined *quotation* as a String, yet are passing it in as a numeric value. I would suggest changing *quotation* to an Integer, or wrapping its value in quotations when passing it as JSON.